# Activate tab after click on a button

Tags: jquery, html

I want to activate a tab after a click on a button. When I click on the button , the tab pane "bbb" should be the activate one.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#aaa" data-toggle="tab">AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bbb" data-toggle="tab">BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ccc" data-toggle="tab">CCC</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
     <div class="tab-pane active" id="aaa">
          <div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" aria-label="Left Align" onclick="activateTab('bbb')" name="activateUser">
                                    Change active tab
              </button>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="bbb">...Content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="ccc">...Content...</div>
</div>
```

```
function activateTab(tab){
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};
```

Here is an example, that doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/z76sy86z/

Comment: It seems to work fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z76sy86z/2/).

Comment: In my project it doesn't work. Could it due on that line: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script> ? It's embeded before the bootsrap link.

Comment: Could be. Can you move the function definition after the jquery is added?

Comment: That's already done. I'm trying to improve the code. The current version has this snippet <li class="<?php
        if(isset($_POST['kw']) ){
            echo '';
        }else{
            echo 'active';
        }
        ?> Could be here a collision?

Answer (score 1):

The function activateTab() is onload function as default option on jsfiddle. It is not on global scope.

You can use Load Type to No wrap from options or easier to do:

```
window.activateTab = function(tab) {  
   $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

don't separate   function from html set all together into html like the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function activateTab(tab){
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
};</script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#aaa" data-toggle="tab">AAA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bbb" data-toggle="tab">BBB</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ccc" data-toggle="tab">CCC</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="tabs">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="aaa">
                                <div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" aria-label="Left Align" onclick="activateTab('bbb')" name="activateUser">
                                        Change active tab
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                           </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="bbb">...Content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="ccc">...Content...</div>
</div>
```